# Yii1: How to use concat function in mysq like query

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii, yii1.x

I want to use `Mysql Concat Function` in `like expression`. 
 I want to merge `firstname` and `lastname` as `fullname` and get matched results according to the `fullname`. 
 I have tried this in YII1. Below is my code:

```
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->select = "*";
    $criteria->select = 'CONCAT(firstname , "" ,  lastname) AS fullname';
    $criteria->addCondition('fullname LIKE :match');
    $criteria->params = array(':match' => $query);
    $models = User::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Below is the generated error message:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'fullname' in 'where clause'
(Error 500)
    CDbCommand::fetchColumn() failed: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054
Unknown column 'fullname' in 'where clause'. The SQL statement executed
was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `members` `t` WHERE fullname LIKE :match.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not expert int Yii but you need to add `CONCAT(firstname , "" ,  lastname)` in the condition itself since alias can not be used in where.

Comment: $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria->select = '*';
        $criteria->addCondition('CONCAT(firstname, lastname) AS fullname  LIKE :match'); but the problem remains same

Comment: no `$criteria->addCondition('CONCAT(firstname , "" ,  lastname) LIKE :match');`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the fullname afterwards, you can just use the CONCAT method in the WHERE clause:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addCondition('CONCAT(userId , " " , username) LIKE :match');
$criteria->params = array(':match' => $query);
$models = User::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

However, if you do want to keep the fullname in the SELECT clause, you can only use this alias in the HAVING clause:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->select = '*, CONCAT(userId , " " , username) AS fullname';
$criteria->having = 'fullname LIKE :match';
$criteria->params = array(':match' => $query);
$models = User::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Please note that your User model should have a fullname attribute in this case, otherwise you won't be able to access the fullname field.

Comment: yes i have added public $fullname property for model user and it is working now

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a more OO-fashioned way to use `SQL Functions`(@JonathanStevens's answer is correct btw):

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();    
    $criteria->select = ['*', new \CDbExpression("CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName) as fullname")];
    $criteria->addCondition('CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName) LIKE :match'); <<<< This is still a problem
    $criteria->params = array(':match' => $query); 
    $models = User::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

**UPDATE**

If you are using `Mysql` the problem is using this aggregate column(fullname) in where clause. 
If you *just select* that column(fullname) and get it by an artificial property in your model, it is ok **but** if you want to use it in `where clause` of a query, it is impossible because it is a restricted by MYSQL server. This is the error you will get:

`#1054 - Unknown column 'fullname' in 'where clause'`

So you need to repeat your SQL function(concat) in where clause too(you can not use alias columns in where clause).

Comment: Indeed, but you can use the alias if you move the condition to the `having` clause.

Comment: Oh, it took me a whole day to form the $criteria->select with my needs.

In my experiments I got to the point that commas in $criteria->select interfere with Yii, but I never used a CDbExpression earlier.

And bingo :) Yii is not intended for serious development...
Thank you, Mohamad.

Comment: I hope that it could help. :)

Comment: @JonathanStevens The problem with having is that it can not be evaluated before grouping criteria, the `where` clause is always preferable, performance-wise.